# POST-request to node.js server and receiving a response (Express.js framework)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to send a POST-reqeust to node.js server with my data from client side? And how to get a response from the server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup a POST route on your express app

```
app.post("/hello", function(req, res) {
  console.log("post received");
  console.log("foo", req.params.foo); //bar
});
```

Send a post request to it

```
<form action="/hello" method="post">
  <input name="foo" value="bar">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I recommend you check out the [express api docs](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html)

Comment: thanks you, but how to send a POST request without form?

Comment: If I need to send a request from the client-side? What can I do?